# Disable Conversation View in Exchange 2019 Web Access (Web Outlook)

Tags: email, exchange, outlook-web-access

there are many tutorials online on how to disable the conversation view in Outlook Webaccess, but I think this option was only available for WebOWA 2016 or prior. The 2019 version only allows the user to sort conversations ascending or descending.

Can somebody confirm that?

Or does the exchange administrator have to change a setting to allow users to disable the conversation view?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option to turn off conversation view under a single drop down called filter.
However, you need to change the setting for each folder.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I needed!